# How do I execute asynchronous queries on Sprint data + JPA custom repository impl?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this custom query (just a simple example):

```
public List<ProdutoEntity> findByDescricaoStartsWithCustom(String desc) {
  String query =
      "SELECT p FROM ProdutoEntity p WHERE p.descricao LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:descricao),'%') " +
          "AND p.situacao = 'A' ORDER BY p.descricao ASC";

  TypedQuery<ProdutoEntity> tpQuery = em.createQuery(query, ProdutoEntity.class);
  tpQuery.setParameter("descricao", desc);

  return tpQuery.getResultList();
}
```

How do I change it to return CompletableFuture and execute asynchronous?

I want it to work like this would:

```
public interface ProdutoRepository extends CrudRepository<ProdutoEntity, Integer> {

  @Async
  CompletableFuture<List<ProdutoEntity>> findByDescricaoStartsWith(
      @Param("descricao") String descricao);
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I did this, not sure if it's correct. Looks too simple.

```
public CompletableFuture<List<ProdutoEntity>> findByDescricaoStartsWithCustom(String desc) {

  CompletableFuture<List<ProdutoEntity>> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    String query =
        "SELECT p FROM ProdutoEntity p WHERE p.descricao LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:descricao),'%') " +
            "AND p.situacao = 'A' ORDER BY p.descricao ASC";

    TypedQuery<ProdutoEntity> tpQuery = em.createQuery(query, ProdutoEntity.class);
    tpQuery.setParameter("descricao", desc);

    return tpQuery.getResultList();
  });

  return cf;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're facing? "Too simple" doesn't sound like a problem :) Is something not working? Are you not getting results from the `CompleteableFuture`?

Comment: We will build a rest service that must scale very well, so doing the queries async will help that. This example is working, but since I'm new to java and spring, and I did not find anything related googling around, I am not sure if it is implemented right.